# How to use a javascript from Composer package in Symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony, composer-php

I've required `vsn4ik/bootstrap-checkbox` in my Symfony project.

How do I now access to the javascript file it contains?

The only way was:

```
 {% javascripts
    '%kernel.root_dir%/vendor/vsn4ik/bootsrap-checkbox/js/bootstrap-checkbox.js'
    filter='?uglifyjs2'
 %}
```

But PHPStorm won't recognize it. Says 'missing asset'.
It does work in the web app.

Also when I do `php bin/console asset:install` it won't install anything.

Comment: `%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/vsn4ik/bootsrap-checkbox/js/bootstrap-checkbox.js`

Comment: asset:install will only install assets from dependencies that are place in the public resources directory. Seeing the path your requiring, the javascript file is placed somewhere else and thus will not be installed as an asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use checkbox but I use the bootstrap slider like this:

assets.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ AppBundle ]

    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
        jsqueeze: ~
    assets:
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            filters: [ jsqueeze ]

        jquery:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.js"
            filters: [ jsqueeze ]

        slider_js:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js"
            filters: [ jsqueeze ]
        slider_css:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/css/bootstrap-slider.css"
            filters: [cssrewrite, scssphp]
```

and then in my twig files:

```
{% javascripts '@jquery' '@bootstrap_js' '@slider_js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I'm sure you can use the same approach in your usecase